# Regular packing of an infinite number of infinitely long cylinders in 3d space

Tags: geometry, polyhedra, packing-problem

Is it possible to pack an infinite number of congruent infinitely long cylinders into 3 dimensional space in a regular pattern? Another condition is that an equal number of the cylinders must be perpendicular to each face of some regular polyhedron.

Comment: This may have applications in the placement of carbon nanotubes in a way that makes them strong along several directions